# Mysql is not returning records with NULL value

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have a column in my table as supplier_id. When I apply the where condition as `supplier_id <> 2` then it is not returning the records that have NULL in the supplier_id column.

**Here is my query:**

```
select * from materials where supplier_id <> 2;
```

However, when I'm trying with `where supplier_id <> 2 or supplier_id is null` then it returns valid records.

Comment: This is not a question. It's a fact.

Comment: This should be answered with try: `select * from materials where IFNULL(supplier_id,0)  <> 2;`, just to make sure the next error is *avoided*... 

Comment: @Luuk - Thanks it's working fine. But can you explain why NULL values are ignored in the simple where clause?

Comment: @Luuk The "next error" would be `IFNULL(supplier_id,0) <> ?` when you bind `0`. It should rather be `IFFNULL(supplier_id <> ?, TRUE)`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel: a _starting_ mysql user would probably type my solution earlier, than yours, but they both should not be  used, because there's a function used which makes mysql check every row of the table, making this a slow solution.

Comment: @JasmelSingh: see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-null.html for an explantion about using NULL.

Comment: @Luuk Right - and I wrote "rather". I would actually use `or supplier_id is null` which is contained in the question itself and is probably the only [effective range condition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/range-optimization.html#range-access-single-part) of all potential answers here. But I doubt that even in that case the engine would choose to use an index. The table must be full of rows with `supplier_id = 2`. So it might not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Most comparisons with a `NULL` value return `NULL` -- and `WHERE` clauses filter out `NULL` values.  This is true of both `=` and `<>`.

One option is a `NULL` safe operator:

```
WHERE NOT supplier_id <=> 2
```

Note that the SQL standard here would be:

```
WHERE supplier_id IS DISTINCT FROM 2
```

But MySQL has its own operator.

Or explicitly take `NULL`s into account:

```
WHERE supplier_id <> 2 OR supplier_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Only *calculations* involving NULLs result in NULL, but any *comparison* to NULL results in `UNKNOWN`, it's a three-valued logic.

Comment: @dnoeth . . . If you run `select NULL = NULL` in MySQL, you will get `NULL`, not "UNKNOWN".  In any case, the semantics of `NULL` should follow the meaning of "UNKNOWN" so there is little or no difference in what we are describing.

Comment: Maybe little difference, but Three-Valued-Logic is a basic concept in SQL. Btw, even MySQL returns `0,0,1` for `SELECT (NULL = 1) IS TRUE, (NULL = 1) IS FALSE, (NULL = 1) IS UNKNOWN` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Any comparison to `NULL` with the use of the operators `=`, `<`, `>` or `<>` returns `NULL` as a result.
So if the result is **not** `TRUE` then the condition:

```
where supplier_id <> 2
```

will filter out these rows with `supplier_id` equal to `NULL`.
 
So you must use:

```
where supplier_id <> 2 or supplier_id is null
```

or use MySql's NULL safe operator:

```
where supplier_id <=> 2
```

which does exactly the same.

Comment: Only *calculations* involving NULLs result in NULL, but any *comparison* to NULL results in `UNKNOWN`, it's a three-valued logic.

Comment: @dnoeth `select null = 2` returns `null`: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5GQwn8TcYL7o9VCjzTqp8/0

Comment: Also: *... the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL* from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: I wouldn't consider MySQL as an authority regarding Standard SQL :-) E.g. Standard SQL's definition of a `<comparison predicate>`: *The result of:
X <comp op> Y
is determined as follows.
Case:
a) If at least one of XV and YV is the null value, then
X <comp op> Y
is Unknown.* Or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL)#Comparisons_with_NULL_and_the_three-valued_logic_(3VL)

Comment: MySql is the only authority regarding MYSql and this is the tag of the question that I answered.

Comment: well, there's also the `sql` tag :-) *Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL.*

Comment: Then maybe all questions tagged with MySql and SQL should use only standard SQL and not MySql's specific features or extensions?

Comment: Of course not, but every SQL dialect is based on Three-valued Logic

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <>.
A NULL value is different from a zero value or a field that contains spaces. A field with a NULL value is one that has been left blank during record creation.

This tag <> mean not equal to. According to your query it shows results which have  supplier_id  except than 2 
select * from materials where supplier_id <> 2 or supplier_id is null;

It will give u your expected output.